# ¿Como aplico DFS (Depth FIrst Search) ? - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo que aplicar el algoritmo de DFS (depth first search)
teniendo en cuenta que tengo los siguiente vertices

> Alfa,Beta,Gamma,Delta,Epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta,Iota,Kappa

y tengo las siguientes aristas en una la matriz

> 0,76000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 76000,0,0,0,240000,0,0,0,360000,0
>
> 0,0,0,10000,0,0,0,120000,0,360000
>
> 20000,0,10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 0,240000,0,0,0,0,60000,0,0,0
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,30000,0,120000,0
>
> 0,0,0,0,60000,30000,0,0,0,0
>
> 0,0,120000,0,0,0,0,0,0,180000
>
> 0,360000,0,0,0,120000,0,0,0,0
>
> 0,0,360000,0,0,0,0,180000,0,0

Hasta donde pude entender realize el grafo para poder ir comprobando resultados, segun yo el grafo tendria que tener la siguiente estructura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces me piden que realize un programa que me de

1- Todos los caminos desde un origen a un destino( el origen y destino lo ingresa el usuario  ).

2- Todos los vertices que se encuentran a una distancia dada desde un vertice origen (la distancia esta dada por el valor de las aristas por ejmplo del Alfa hasta Delta hay un valor de 20000).

Comment: Hola @Shiki. La manera de hacer la pregunta no es la correcta para este sitio, veo que ya tienes medallas pero mira este enlace para ver como realizar una consulta de calidad y que te podamos echar una mano: [ask]

Comment: Okas gracias por la sugerencia ahi cambie el titulo.