# Problema con combinaciones DFS - C#

Tags: c#

Pude resolver el primer punto pero despues de hacer un par de pruebas me di cuenta que tenia un error , cuando ingreso el origen Alfa destino Zeta devuelve 2 caminos  posibles, lo cual segun el grafico es correcto, pero cuando ingreso origen kappa  destino zeta muestra 2 caminos posibles cuando en realidad son 4.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1- Todos los caminos desde un origen a un destino( el origen y destino lo ingresa el usuario ).

```
 static void DFS(vertice origen , vertice destino,grafo graf,string path )
    {

        origen.visitado = true;
        path = path + origen.nombre + ",";

        if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            destino.visitado = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int con = 0; con < origen.adyacencias.Length; con++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(path);
                if (origen.adyacencias[con] > 0 & graf.vertices[con].visitado == false)
                {
                    graf.vertices[con].visitado = false;

                    DFS(graf.vertices[con], destino, graf, path);
                }

            }

        }


    }
// CLASES GRAFO Y VERTICE
class grafo
{
    public vertice[] vertices = new vertice[10];
}

class vertice
{
    public string nombre = "";
    public string diametro = "";
    public string promedio = "";
    public bool visitado = false;
    public float[] adyacencias = new float[10] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la forma que tienes de controlar si ya has pasado por un vértice: poner la propiedad `visitado` del vértice a `true`.

Lo que deberías comprobar es si la ruta actual ha pasado ya por este vértice pero, al comprobar la propiedad `visitado`, lo que haces es comprobar si alguna de las rutas ha pasado por ese vértice.

Para comprobar si el vértice ha sido recorrido por la ruta actual podías mirar si existe en el string `path`.

En este ejemplo utilizo una expresión regular para ver si ya está incluido en la ruta actual:

```
static void DFS(vertice origen, vertice destino, grafo graf, string path)
{
    path = (path == String.Empty ? path : $"{path},") + origen.nombre;

    if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int con = 0; con < origen.adyacencias.Length; con++)
        {
            var visitado = Regex.IsMatch(path, $@"\b{graf.vertices[con].nombre}\b");
            if (origen.adyacencias[con] > 0 && !visitado)
            {
                DFS(graf.vertices[con], destino, graf, path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para el ejemplo de origen Kappa - destino Zeta, obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código completo de la aplicación de consola para realizar pruebas:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp_C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var grafo = CrearGrafo();
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca Origen");
            var origen = Console.ReadKey();
            int nodoOrigen = Int32.Parse(origen.KeyChar.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nIntroduzca Destino");
            var destino = Console.ReadKey();
            int nodoDestino = Int32.Parse(destino.KeyChar.ToString());
            string path = "";
            Console.WriteLine();
            DFS(grafo.vertices[nodoOrigen], grafo.vertices[nodoDestino], grafo, path);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static grafo CrearGrafo()
        {
            var result = new grafo
            {
                vertices =
                {
                    [0] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Alfa",
                        adyacencias = { [1] = 20000, [2] = 76000 }
                    },
                    [1] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Delta",
                        adyacencias = { [0] = 20000, [3] = 10000 }
                    },
                    [2] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Beta",
                        adyacencias = { [0] = 76000, [4] = 360000, [5] = 240000 }
                    },
                    [3] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Gamma",
                        adyacencias = { [1] = 10000, [6] = 360000, [7] = 120000 }
                    },
                    [4] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Iota",
                        adyacencias = { [2] = 360000, [8] = 120000 }
                    },
                    [5] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Epsilon",
                        adyacencias = { [2] = 240000, [9] = 60000 }
                    },
                    [6] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Kappa",
                        adyacencias = { [3] = 360000, [7] = 180000 }
                    },
                    [7] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Theta",
                        adyacencias = { [3] = 120000, [6] = 180000 }
                    },
                    [8] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Zeta",
                        adyacencias = { [4] = 120000, [9] = 30000 }
                    },
                    [9] = new vertice
                    {
                        nombre = "Eta",
                        adyacencias = { [5] = 60000, [8] = 30000 }
                    }
                }
            };

            return result;
        }

        static void DFS(vertice origen, vertice destino, grafo graf, string path)
        {
            path = (path == String.Empty ? path : $"{path},") + origen.nombre;

            if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(path);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int con = 0; con < origen.adyacencias.Length; con++)
                {
                    var visitado = Regex.IsMatch(path, $@"\b{graf.vertices[con].nombre}\b");
                    if (origen.adyacencias[con] > 0 && !visitado)
                    {
                        DFS(graf.vertices[con], destino, graf, path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // CLASES GRAFO Y VERTICE
        class grafo
        {
            public vertice[] vertices = new vertice[10];
        }

        class vertice
        {
            public string nombre = "";
            public string diametro = "";
            public string promedio = "";
            public bool visitado = false;
            public float[] adyacencias = new float[10];
        }

    }
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que los valores a introducir son los índices de los vértices origen y destino. Por ejemplo para probar con la ruta Kappa-Zeta los valores a introducir serían 6 (índice de vértice Kappa) y 8 (índice de vértice Zeta)

Yo te propondría también una manera diferente de mantener la información del grafo: manteniendo dos colecciones diferentes, una con los vértices y otra con las conexiones entre ellos.

Aquí te dejo el código de una aplicación de consola utilizando esta opción:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp_C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var grafo = new Grafo(new[]
                {"Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Theta", "Eta", "Zeta", "Iota", "Kappa"});
            grafo.CrearConexion("Alfa", "Delta", 20000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Alfa", "Beta", 76000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Delta", "Gamma", 10000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Beta", "Iota", 360000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Beta", "Epsilon", 240000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Gamma", "Kappa", 360000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Gamma", "Theta", 120000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Iota", "Zeta", 120000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Epsilon", "Eta", 60000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Kappa", "Theta", 180000);
            grafo.CrearConexion("Zeta", "Eta", 30000);

            var rutas = grafo.ObtenerTodasLasRutas("Kappa", "Zeta");

            foreach (var ruta in rutas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", ruta));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        class Grafo
        {

            private readonly List<Conexion> _conexiones;
            private readonly IEnumerable<string> _vertices;

            public Grafo(IEnumerable<string> vertices)
            {
                _vertices = vertices;
                _conexiones = new List<Conexion>();
            }

            public void CrearConexion(string nodo1, string nodo2, int distancia)
            {
                if (!_vertices.Contains(nodo1)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nodo1), $"El nodo {nodo1} no existe");
                if (!_vertices.Contains(nodo2)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nodo2), $"El nodo {nodo2} no existe");
                if (nodo1 == nodo2) throw new ArgumentException("No se puede crear una conexión al mismo nodo");
                if (_conexiones.Any(c => c.Nodo1 == nodo1 && c.Nodo2 == nodo2 || c.Nodo1 == nodo2 && c.Nodo2 == nodo1))
                    throw new ArgumentException($"La conexión entre {nodo1} y {nodo2} ya existe");
                if (distancia <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(distancia));

                _conexiones.Add(new Conexion(nodo1, nodo2, distancia));
            }

            public IEnumerable<List<string>> ObtenerTodasLasRutas(string origen, string destino)
            {
                if (!_vertices.Contains(origen)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(origen), $"El nodo {origen} no existe");
                if (!_vertices.Contains(destino)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(destino), $"El nodo {destino} no existe");

                var ruta = new List<string> {origen};
                return CrearTodasLasRutas(ruta, destino);
            }

            private IEnumerable<List<string>> CrearTodasLasRutas(List<string> ruta, string destino)
            {
                var result = new List<List<string>>();
                var actual = ruta.Last();
                if (actual == destino)
                {
                    result.Add(ruta);
                }
                else
                {
                    var nodosSiguientes = _conexiones
                        .Where(c => c.Nodo1 == actual || c.Nodo2 == actual)
                        .Select(c => c.Nodo1 == actual ? c.Nodo2 : c.Nodo1)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Where(n => !ruta.Contains(n));
                    foreach (var siguiente in nodosSiguientes)
                    {
                        var rutaSiguiente = new List<string>(ruta) {siguiente};
                        result.AddRange(CrearTodasLasRutas(rutaSiguiente, destino));
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        public struct Conexion
        {
            public Conexion(string nodo1, string nodo2, int distancia)
            {
                Nodo1 = nodo1;
                Nodo2 = nodo2;
                Distancia = distancia;
            }
            public string Nodo1 { get; }
            public string Nodo2 { get; }
            public int Distancia { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Habia pensado eso que decis de hecho lo sigo planteando asi. El problema esta en el punto de corte, porque sino seguiria haciendo combinaciones y comprobando si existen o si no existen aunq ya las haya repetido.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres. Si pruebas el código que te pongo en el ejemplo verás que funciona bien. No deberían repetirse nunca.

Comment: Si funciona pero el problema es el mismo, nose si tienes como implementar el grafo que puse como ejemplo, si yo pongo origen Alfa y destino Zeta muestra los caminos posibles de manera correcta tal como lo hace el original que pase, PEEERO cuando pones origen Kappa destino Zeta se muere a diferencia del que habia hecho que muestra 2 caminos cuando en realidad son 4, pero con lo que me pasaste no muestra nada directamente se muere...

Comment: Habría que ver cómo tienes implementado el grafo, tal y como lo he montado yo me devuelve las 4 rutas sin ningún problema

Comment: Como te decia si funciona ante caminos simples aqui te dejo mi matriz de adyacencias https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121739/como-aplico-dfs-depth-first-search-c

Comment: He añadido una imagen con el resultado que obtengo con origen Kappa y destino Zeta.

Comment: añadiste algo mas despues de using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: Edito y pongo el código completo

Comment: He añadido también otro ejemplo utilizando una estructura diferente para mantener la información del grafo. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

No estoy muy seguro de como funcionan internamente tus clases `vertice` o  `grafo`, pero viendo tu codigo, creo que de esta forma resuelve tu problema. Recuerda siempre llamar a esa funcion con `suma=0`. Saludos.

```
static void DFS_suma(vertice origen, float distancia,float suma, grafo graf, string path)
    {
        //path = path + origen.nombre + ",";

        if (suma > distancia) {
            return;
        }

        if (suma == distancia)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(suma);
            //suma = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            for (int con = 0; con < origen.adyacencias.Length; con++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(path);
                if (origen.adyacencias[con] > 0 )
                {

                    DFS_suma(graf.vertices[con], distancia,suma+origen.adyacencias[con], graf, path);
                }

            }

        }


    }
```